# Removing spaces but leaving line breaks JS or jQuery in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, whitespace, extra

I want to remove extra spaces at the beginning and the end of lines, but keep the line breaks, this is what I tried.

```js
function removeSpaces(string) {
 return string.split(' ').join('');
}
```

```html
<center>
 <form action="getid.php" method="post">
  <textarea name="items" id="itemNames" cols="100" rows="10" onblur="this.value=removeSpaces(this.value);"></textarea><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Get dem IDs">
  <input type="button" id="remove" value="Remove extra spaces">
 </form>
</center>
```

But instead, it's removing ALL the spaces, and the '\n'

Comment: Not sure why you tagged Java. Will remove.

Comment: I removed the Java tag since this question has nothing to do with Java.

Comment: Meant to tag Javascript, sorry.

Comment: Are you sure ? I tested it. no line break found

Comment: Exactly, I need the line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would most definitely remove all spaces.

```
string.split(' ')
```

splits up your entire string by spaces, which includes spaces before, after and within the string itself.

My approach is as follows:

```
function removeSpaces(string) {
    // Remove leading spaces
    while(string.indexOf(' ') === 0) {
        string = string.substr(1);
    }
    // Remove trailing spaces
    while(string[string.length-1] === ' ') {
        string = string.substr(0, string.length-1);
    }
    return string;
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Tried it, removes the spaces that you type, but not from the text when you copy / paste.

Comment: Could you provide an example input that you used to test?

Comment: I've updated your jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Lov705o7/1/

Let me know if you have doubts on the code.

Comment: Same thing
here's what I'm trying
http://pastebin.com/e5R1zXez
edit : doesn't need to be JS, anything that works is fine tbh

Comment: I don't get what's not working for you. Tried both typing and copy pasting and it all works as expected. What did you try to copy-paste?

Comment: I linked a pastebin to what I tried in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeSpaces(string) {
        // Remove line breaks
        var str = string.replace(/\n/g,"");     
        return str.split(' ').join('');   
}
```

Comment: <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<center>
 <form action="getid.php" method="post">
  <textarea name="items" id="itemNames" cols="100" rows="10" onblur="this.value=removeSpaces(this.value);"></textarea><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Get dem IDs">
  <input type="button" id="remove" value="Remove extra spaces">
 </form>
</center>
<script>
 function removeSpaces(string) {
    //Remove line breaks
        var str = string.replace(/\n/g,"");  
        return str.split(' ').join(''); 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

just use `.trim()`

```
function removeSpaces(string) {
      return string.trim();
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2dus6L83/
Try it with
http://pastebin.com/e5R1zXez
Didn't work for me

Comment: yes ,jsfiddle is not worked .But put this function at the bottom of html box in jsfiddle! That will work